# ConfigurationElement—Combination of Attributes?

Tags: .net-2.0, configurationelement, configurationproperty

Say I have defined a custom `AdapterElement : ConfigurationElement` with properties `Type`, `Name` and `Version`. Since `Name` and `Version` uniquelly identifies the `Type` property, I would like to *enforce* the configuration file to have one of the following structures:

```
<adapter type="TypeOfAdapter"/>
<adapter name="NameOfAdapter" version="VersionOfAdapter"/>
```

I could easily mark those three properties with `IsRequired = false` and let users specify the combination the want. However, the following combinations are not valid and I would like to forbid them:

```
<adapter type="TypeOfAdapter" version="VersionOfAdapter"/>
<adapter type="TypeOfAdapter" name="NameOfAdapter"/>
```

Is there any easy way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do a bit of reading around to find answers on this one.

How about adding a PostDeserialise check for validity to your AdapterElement class?

```
protected override void PostDeserialize()
{
   bool isValid = Type != null && Name == null && Version == null
               || Type == null && Name != null && Version != null;
   if (!isValid)
   {
      throw new ArgumentException("Must specify either Type or Name and Version");
   }
   base.PostDeserialize();
}
```

According to [a blog I found](http://blog.rjcox.co.uk/2010/05/23/custom-configuration-3/) there is no more obvious way of verifying validity of Multiple Attributes on a single configuration section - but it appears to be true for configuation elements too.